# Can I set image to acrofield in iText7.NET

Tags: c#, .net, barcode, itext7

I want to upgrade from iTextSharp to iText7.
I cant set the image of PdfButtonField to an System.Drawing.Image in the past.
But now in iText7, the PdfButtonFormField.SetImage(string sImagePah) can only acccept file path.
I create an System.Drawing.Image the fly, How can I set the image the an AcroField in iText7.NET ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SetValue` method and provide Base64-encoded image value there.

Example code to covert `System.Drawing.Image` to a Base64 string:

```
public static string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
}
```

Example code to set the image to the form field:

```
PdfButtonFormField field = ...;
field.SetValue(ImageToBase64(image));
```